# How would I modify rmchr to use pointers. I've been able to get my code to run the way it is but the assignment requires pointers to be used

Tags: c, string, pointers

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void rmchr(char *string, char a) 
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++) //loop till '\0' character 
    { 
        if (string[i] == a) { //check given character  is equal to chr at i
            for (j = i; string[j] != '\0'; j++)  // loop from i till string end
            {
                string[j] = string[j+ 1]; // swap value with next char
            }
            string[j] = '\0';  //assign terminating char to lasts index of string
            i--; //decrement i
        }

    }
}

int main() 
{
    char str1[] = "abracadabra";
    char str2[] = "abracadabra";
    char str3[] = "abracadabra";
    char str4[] = "aaaa";
    char str5[] = "aaaa";
    printf("Before rmchr function call string= %s\n", str1);
    rmchr(str1, 'a');
    printf("After rmchr function call string= %s\n\n", str1);

    printf("Before rmchr function call string= %s\n", str2);
    rmchr(str2, 'b');
    printf("After rmchr function call string= %s\n\n", str2);

    printf("Before rmchr function call string= %s\n", str3);
    rmchr(str3, 'n');
    printf("After rmchr function call string= %s\n\n", str3);

    printf("Before rmchr function call string= %s\n", str4);
    rmchr(str4, 'a');
    printf("After rmchr function call string= %s\n\n", str4);

    printf("Before rmchr function call string= %s\n", str5);
    rmchr(str5, 'n');
    printf("After rmchr function call string= %s\n", str5);
}
```

/*Output

Before rmchr function call string= abracadabra
After rmchr function call string= brcdbr

Before rmchr function call string= abracadabra
After rmchr function call string= aracadara

Before rmchr function call string= abracadabra
After rmchr function call string= abracadabra

Before rmchr function call string= aaaa
After rmchr function call string=

Before rmchr function call string= aaaa
After rmchr function call string= aaaa

---

Process exited after 0.015 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
*/

Comment: It is using pointers....

Comment: that's what i thought too but my professor handed it back to me saying that I needed pointers where i have "string[i]" and "string[j]... so confused

Comment: You professor should read a good C book. You cannot use arrays for anything usefull, it is all pointers. He better should point you at writing const-correct code and not use obsolesecence function declarators like `main()`, which should be the prototype-style `main(void)`.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `a[i]` is defined to be equivalent to `*(a + i)`. Modifying your code with that transformation would be sufficient to satisfy the pointer requirement as I understand your question to be about.

If you want to be incrementing and decrementing pointer variables rather than integer indexes, then consider that:

```
char *p = string;
int i = 0;

while (string[i]) {
    assert(*p == string[i]);
    ++i;
    ++p;
}
```

Comment: The index operator is defined to wok on pointers anyway. I don't see a problekm writing readable code instead of the much less clear addition/derefence syntax.

Comment: @Olaf: I agree that there are better ways to teach how pointers work.